# Unable to disable binding defined by undo-tree

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, undo-tree-mode, eval-after-load

There are two bindings for `undo-tree-undo`(`C-_` and `C-/`) and `undo-tree-redo`(`M-_` and `C-?`) defined in [undo-tree](https://github.com/emacsmirror/undo-tree), but now I don't want those bindings(`delete` those), I just want to bind `C-z` to `undo-tree-undo` and `C-S-z` to `undo-tree-redo`(short and simple), I tried

```
(define-key undo-tree-map (kbd "C-_") nil)
```

or

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-_"))
```

to delete the bindings, they all doesn't work(only work for current session), if I restart Emacs, the `C-_` will still be bound to `undo-tree-undo`.

But if I set above two lines at the same time, the binding will be gone, that's really weird, how can I use one line to delete the bound.

BTW, if you can delete the old bindings and set the new binding(`C-z`) at the same time, that would be better?

Comment: I'm going to suggest something that no forum participant will like:  It may be time to take complete control of your libraries and modify them to suit your personal needs instead of trying to tweak them here and there.

Answer (score 6):

To make these bindings persistent, put them into your init file. For them to be able to redefine the undo-tree keymap, undo-tree has to be active first. This can either be guaranteed by enabling undo-tree first (which only works after the packages have been enabled in the respective `after-init-hook` or after using `package-initialize` in your init file) or by applying them after its file has been loaded with `eval-after-load`.

As for rebinding existing functionality, you're able to remap a command to another or swap out a command for the keybinding in question.  Neither of those are what you're after.  Here's a snippet you can put in your init file that's using `eval-after-load' and explicitly rebinds everything:

```
(eval-after-load 'undo-tree
  '(progn
     (define-key undo-tree-map (kbd "C-/") nil)
     (define-key undo-tree-map (kbd "C-_") nil)
     (define-key undo-tree-map (kbd "C-?") nil)
     (define-key undo-tree-map (kbd "M-_") nil)
     (define-key undo-tree-map (kbd "C-z") 'undo-tree-undo)
     (define-key undo-tree-map (kbd "C-S-z") 'undo-tree-redo)))
```

Comment: I have `package-initialize` at the beginning of my init file. Although I got `C-/` bound to `helm-semantic-or-imenu` in my init file, `C-?` bound to `ispell-complete-word` in my init file, they still have to be `(define-key undo-tree-map (kbd "...") nil)`(or the manually binding to `helm..` and `ispell..` will not work), the two and `M-_` can be disable using only one line without `eval-after-load`, but the goddamn `C-_` is still there. I think maybe the `C-_` is builtin for `undo` in `emacs -q`, and `M-_` is not.

Comment: I'll just take special care of `C-_`, put the two lines at the same time if there is no better solution. But still thanks.